# XIB is cut off during runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface, builder

I'm currently in the process of updating my App for the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus. 
While everything worked fine under iOS 7, I now get a cut off XIB, that only shows the left upper quarter of the view during runtime. Everything looks like it's supposed to be in the Xcode 6 preview window.
The changes I made since my last iOS 7 release are:
-Auto layout enabled
-Set constraints
-Set and iPhone 6 and 6 Plus LaunchImage. 
Constraints are set. 
I'm sorry, but I can't post any images yet..I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Sadly, I did not. I switched my entire App over to Storyboards shortly after. Apple has made it very hard to publish Apps with a Deployment Target below iOS 5.1.1 recently, by forcing us to publish 64 bit binaries. Therefore I don't think it is worth the hassle to deal with XIBs anymore (I used to love XIBs back in the day!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the loop for those of you reading this still using XIB's I figured out the issue.  You have to use code to set the bound and autoresizing masks.

```html
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // resize to fit window
    [[self view] setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self view].autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
}
```